# Uploading Edited Webpage Kills PHP

Tags: php, html, web-hosting, filepath

For comedic purposes, I took a Wikipedia article, downloaded it, and edited the HTML so as to get the page to say particular amusing things I wanted it to. I want to link the page to other people, so I made an account on 000webhost where I uploaded it.

I made sure to upload the folder with all the resources. I checked the reference in the html and it seems to be going to the right place,

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./index_files/load.php">`

but opening the page, I just get it unformatted, like the way it might look on a old phone or when dealing with extremely slow internet speeds.

I assume the error has something to do with the filepath. I tried moving the resources folder (it is, in fact, called index_files) to a couple of different locations (inside "temp", inside "public_html", and also inside the highest level of the directory, "/", which is where "temp" and "public_html" reside. None of them worked.

Just to be clear, when I try opening the webpage from the identical html file on my desktop, it works just fine (except that most of the images won't load).

Any suggestions?
Thanks a ton (I need to have figured this out by Wednesday, preferably)

Disclaimer: I know very little about HTML or CSS

Update: Some of the images (which wouldn't load from the file on my hard drive) are in fact loading when I use the link

Comment: What's in `load.php`? Does the network panel show that as a 404?

Comment: load.php, I assume is the file that handles the formatting for the Wikipedia page. Again, I didn't write most of this code, and I definitely didn't touch the PHP. I just changed some of the text. Also don't know any PHP can't really say much about the file. There's also 4 files called load ( load.php, load(1).php, load(2).php, load(3).php)

Comment: Do you have a local copy of that file?

Comment: Just looked it again. Yes. It says it failed to load the resource for all 4 load files.

Comment: Do you have local copies of those files? Or not?

Comment: Do You mean on my hard drive?

Comment: Yes, and on your server

Comment: Do you even need php for what you are doing? If I was making a parody wikipedia page I would just take page source code (from the browser) and associated images and CSS files and put them in the same folder structure so it is a flat HTML/CSS website.

Comment: Downloading the page, I don't see an associated CSS file at all. Just the HTML, and a folder with images and the PHPs. That's why I assumed they were important. Also, deleting load.php (just the unnumbered one) resulted in the unformatted page. Deleting the other 3 didn't change anything.